# how to truncate eav_attribute_option_value table in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have a shop where some customer information is in the eav_attribute_option_value-table. now I want to truncate this table

Answer (score 0):

simply run `DELETE FROM eav_attribute_option_value` in the your sql manager (PHPMyAdmin, adminer or directly)

Answer (score 0):

you can run one of these queries

`DELETE FROM eav_attribute_option_value`

or directly truncate table.

`TRUNCATE eav_attribute_option_value`